# After running SVD, how do I project new data onto the lower-rank space?

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction, svd

Suppose I have a training data-set *A* which is *m x n*, with samples arranged as rows, and I use *singular value decomposition* to find *k* principal directions defining a lower-rank space, *k < n*.

The output of SVD, named by convention *U, Σ, V* gives me an approximation for my training set: A approximately equal to U Σ transpose(V)

Moreover, the product U Σ is *m x k* with each row representing a vector in the lower-rank space that approximates the corresponding row in the rank-n original space. From this "lossy" data, it is also possible to return to the rank-n space by right-multiplying with *V*.

All of this is fine and well but let's say I now train some learning system using U Σ as my training set instead of the original *A*. In order to later exploit the trained system, I would have to query it using vectors in the lower rank space.

Assuming I have a query vector Q which is *1 x n* and not present in the training set. I want to find the *1 x k* vector in the lower-rank space that most appropriately matches Q. How do I do this?

Or am I completely missing the point of SVD and misunderstanding how it is useful for dimensionality reduction?